# Main Menu for OpenGL game

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I now want to create a menu for the game project am working on.. But the project already have a WinMain class..

So is there any way i can create a new cpp file and in the current WinMain call the window i made in the other cpp file?
And if a button was pressed i want to close the window and open the other one.

So basicaly here i want to replace the WinMain i have right now and in the WinMain call a window that i made in another file.. Is this possible or is there another better way to do it?

Comment: I think usually people use stack or other data structure for menu. So you can save all of your windows (menu, game window, pause menu, options, etc) in a stack, then pop / push it as needed. The window the user sees is the topmost on stack. I'll leave the detailed answer for others, as I've only do this on assignments. HTH.

Comment: The game is already working right now.. Its just that i want a simple menu to be displayed before the game starts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to create a menu application which processes options/settings, user's choices etc before the user presses the Start button to bring up your game application. They stay separated as two entities.
If your current game GUI doesn't have a menu, you can certainly create one such as context (popup) menu, menu bar, etc, which can be stored inside the game cpp file via message map processing.
if these doesn't give you any hint then you may rephrase

> So is there any way i can create a new cpp file and in the current
>   WinMain call the window i made in the other cpp file? And if a button
>   was pressed i want to close the window and open the other one.

Comment: Its hard to explain.. Right now the game starts just like that when i debug.. But i want instead of the WinMain window to pop up now i want it to pop up when you pressed start.. So i would need to replace the WinMain window with the main menu right? But is there a way i can have the main menu window in another .cpp file and then call the window in the WinMain ?